# Variant Array Not Populating Destination Cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a range of data from one tab into another tab in excel using the fastest way in VBA. After some research, I've decided to use a variant array to do so but my code is not returning anything at all in my destination cells. Can someone spot the issue with my sub?

```
Sub array_vt()


Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim Arr2() As Variant
Dim Fcst_Essbase As Worksheet
Dim fcst_tab As Worksheet
Dim fcst_rowcnt As Long

fcst_rowcnt = Sheets("Date Dims").Range("B7")
fcst_rowcnt2 = Sheets("Date Dims").Range("B9")
Set fcst_tab = Sheets("Cartesian Product - Fcst")
Set Fcst_Essbase = Sheets("Fcst Essbase Pull")
Arr = Fcst_Essbase.Range("A4:L" & fcst_rowcnt2)
Arr2 = fcst_tab.Range("A2:L" & fcst_rowcnt)

Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long

Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = fcst_tab.Range("A2")

For R = 4 To UBound(Arr, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
   For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
Destination.Resize(UBound(Arr2, 1), UBound(Arr2, 2)).Value = Arr

       Next C
    Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: For starters, you don't need the two loops: `Destination.Resize(UBound(Arr2, 1), UBound(Arr2, 2)).Value = Arr` is all you need to write an array back to the sheet.

Comment: @BigBen you are saving me today with my beginner VBA troubles. Thank you!

Comment: Though - why are you mixing `Arr2` and `Arr` in that line?

Comment: @BigBen after your advice, I removed the Arr2 variable... `Destination.Resize(fcst_rowcnt, 12).Value = Arr`